# How to hide a private key?

Tags: javascript

I have a private key in my javascript code:

```
var privateKey = "E753A647BDB7BAA1F17DDFD64D3B5D5AB8D6416E6F8E85B8124EB73BB5CD5756";
```

How do I hide the key? Obfuscation is not a good idea.

The private key is in the back end.

Here is an analogy : I am the general of an army ,i write an encrypted secret msg on a piece of paper and the key to decrypt the code on another piece of paper,i trust all to send the encrypted secret msg to the king ,but i trust no one to send the piece of paper with key to the king .I can not move from my position to send the msg my self, how do i send the piece of paper with the key to decrypt the msg to the king if i don't trust no one  ?

Programmers can edit files ,and they see the private key , i want to hide the private key from programmers eyes.

Comment: If something is in your front-end code, you can't hide it, period. You're better off explaining what you're actually trying to do and then someone can propose a commonly used solution for that problem.

Comment: the private key is in the back end

Comment: Oh, so this is a Node application? Still, your problem is very unclear at the moment, please try to elaborate, currently it's not possible to give a reasonable answer.

Comment: The way to hide a key is to use a cryptographic key store. When you start your server, you provide the password to unlock the key store and your server can extract the key.

Comment: If it's in the back end why do you want to hide it? In fact what does "hide it" mean?

Comment: programmers can edit files ,and they see the private key , i want to hide he private key from programmers eyes.

Comment: @alin Lol you can't do this.

Comment: You cannot do that in plain JavaScript code. The only secure way is to protect the key with robust encryption.

Comment: Have you considered blindfolds? :)

Comment: it's a hard problem i know.

Comment: @alin You can store the private key in a protected file that programmers do not have permissions to access. But the programmer could then just write a program to read the file out.

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to solve a social problem with technology, something that generally doesn't really bode well. Instead, you might want to try describing your actual problem on [the Workplace SE site](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/) and consider what your options for communication and leverage are.

Comment: @YoYoYonnY yep i know that also .

Comment: @YoYoYonnY But how would this program access the file if it dosn't have permissions - assuming it is executed from the programmer's limited account? They would need a local exploit, right?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I understand your question but if you mean: "I have some code that is shared between developers (using git or something else). In my code, there is a need for a private key, but I don't want this private key to be shared."

Then here is the solution:

Use a .env file, (don't push this file to your repository):

> PRIVATE_KEY=ABCD1234XYZ

Then, import the file content (if you have a node application, I suggest [dotenv](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv)).

Finally, you will be able to access this value in your code with the following line:

```
const myPrivateKey = process.env.PRIVATEKEY
```

Therefore, your key won't be in your code anymore, but in a .env file on your computer.

Comment: not good as they get access to the server

Comment: Then, there is literally only two solutions left:
1/ Remove their access to the server (use continuous deployment instead)
2/ Trust the developers

Comment: Here is an analogy : I am the general of an army ,i write an encrypted secret msg on a piece of paper and the key to decrypt the code on another piece of paper,i trust all to send the encrypted secret msg to the king ,but i trust no one to send the piece of paper with key to the king .I can not move from my position to send the msg my self, how do i send the piece of paper with the key to decrypt the msg to the king if i don't trust no one ?

Comment: Well.. You can't! Either you trust someone to take the private key to the other king, or you do it yourself. They are call "private" for a reason.

Comment: In your analogy, you use a symmetric encryption (one key to encrypt and one key to decrypt). Maybe what you need is an asymmetric encryption where someone can encrypt using your public key and you can decrypt with your private key ? (and vice-versa)

Comment: To go further in the analogy: you have a room in your castle where you put every keys to the treasure room (the server). And you ask: "How to make sure my valets don't see what is inside my room". Well, don't allow them in the room.